# Custom Data Attributes in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way that we define a custom attribute over a property so that when ever that property is used 1 is added to its amount and stored in database and when ever, I retrieve it from database 1 is subtracted from it?

For example

say this is the emdx class

```
public class book
{
    [Required]
    string author{get;set;}

    [customAttribute]
    int amount{get;set;}
}
```

so what I want is when ever amount is getting stored in database 1 is added into it and when ever I retrieve it 1 get subtracted. I know we can get and set it here but I want to do it using custom attribute because I want to do it on a lot of places and I don't want to write custom code every where.

Comment: using direct ways - no, using something like postsharp.net - likely, what it would do it would change your code during build, so if it is only one place, I would suggest do it manually. On the other hand, I would not place business login into what seems to be model.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want to do this? There may be a solution to your problem, it just wouldn't be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten I want to use data Attributes to encrypt and decrypt a field ...If suppose [encryption] attribute is over a property it should be saved in the database as encrypted and on retrieving it should automatically be decrypted.